# How to get underlying type of generic interface?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
public class TestBase
{
    // implementation
}
public class Test : ICollection<TestBase>
{
    // implementation
}
```

Somewhere else I have a property of the Test type:

```
public Test Test {get;set;}
```

How can I get the underlying type of the ICollection that the Test inherits from?

Comment: Your question really needs to be clarified..  `Test` doesn't inherit from anything, it implements `ICollection<TestBase>`.  Try stating what type you'd expect to get from the method you can't seem to think of: is it `TestBase` or `ICollection`?  There are already answers providing both, and I think you probably want `TestBase`, but it's not clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is `GetGenericArguments()`.

```
var type = typeof(Test);
var collInterface = type.GetInterfaces()[0];
var generic = collInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let x be an instance of a class that implements interfaces. You can get its iterface types as follows:

```
var type = x.GetType();
var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
```

Edit: I had your question wrong: Follow up with "GetGenericArguments()" as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

the `GetInterfaces` method returns all implemented interfaces in current type and its `GetGenericArguments` method returns list of generic arguments witch you can get its base type by `BaseType` property.
this example returns class hierarchy of the generic argument of base interface 
implemented in current class:

var myType = this.GetType().GetInterfaces().First().GetGenericArguments().First();
                    while (myType != null)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(myType.Name);
                    myType = myType.BaseType;
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach of getting the used type in a base interface:

```
private readonly IObjectProvider<Interface> _repositoryInterfaces = 
    Interfaces().That().ImplementInterface(typeof(IRepository<>)).As("Repository Interfaces");

[Fact]
public void RepositoryInterfaces_ShouldBeInTheCorrectNamespace()
{
    // Arrange
    var repos = Interfaces().That().Are(_repositoryInterfaces).GetObjects(Architecture);

    // Act
    // Assert
    foreach (var repo in repos)
    {
        var entityType = repo.GetImplementsInterfaceDependencies().Single().TargetGenericArguments.Single().Type;

        repo.ResidesInNamespace($"Domain.AggregateModels.{entityType.Name}Aggregate").Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

my interfaces look like this:

```
public interface IExampleRepository : IRepository<ExampleEntity>
{ //more methods here }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Type t = typeof(Test);
 MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("MyMethod");
 Type returnvalue = mi.ReturnType;
 Type answer = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(returnvalue);
```

I hope it helps.